# Proof of the Absolute Least Remainder Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have managed to grasp and construct the elementary proofs of the division theorem and the modified version were $0 \leq r < \mid b \mid $, but I am not quite there yet with the absolute least remainder algorithm.

**Theorem:**

If $a, b \in \mathbb{Z} $ and $a, b \neq 0$, then there are unique $q, r \in \mathbb{Z} $ such that:

$a = bq +r, ~~~~ -\frac{|b|}{2} < r \leq \frac{|b|}{2}$

**Proof:**

(here is what I got so far)

There are three things to prove: existence, r conditions and uniqueness.

Consider these two cases:

1. $0 \leq r < \frac{1}{2} |b| $
2. $\frac{1}{2} |b| \leq r < |b|$

We apply the original division algorithm to a.

In the first case, we have:

$a = |b|q' + r$  where $q' = q \frac{|b|}{b} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r$ is in the appropriate range.

In the second case, we have:

$a = |b|q' + r'$ where $q' = (q+1) \frac{|b|}{b} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r' = r - |b|$.

This satisfies the r' criteria i.e. $-\frac{1}{2}|b| \leq r' < 0$.

---

However, I am not sure if this is correct in the first place, or how to connect this to the overarching proof structure of the division algorithm.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think to search for the symbols (only searched for the theory name).

The answer given in that is more than satisfactory for me. I consider this question answered.

Thanks.